# Using list<T> in Microsoft Report Viewer

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer

I'd like to bind a list of objects to a report and show its values.

The sample class looks like this:

```
class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }

    public TestClass(string name, DateTime time)
    {
        Name = name;
        Time = time;
        Numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    }
}
```

I can bind it to a Microsoft Report Viewer and I can show its values without any problem:

```
List<TestClass> testClassList = new List<TestClass>()
{
    new TestClass("a", DateTime.Now), 
    new TestClass("b", DateTime.Now.AddHours(1))
};
this.TestClassBindingSource.DataSource = testClassList;
```

My problem is to show values of the 'Numbers' list of my class. I can not add it to the report when designig, and shows 'error' in the report. Is it possible to show them in the report?

...and by the way: can I localize somehow reportview controls's user interface? As I see it supports only English -and may be some more- but not mine.

Comment: Did you try binding the List to the Table control of the ReportViewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, Since the data member is a List of intergets, you would need to serialize them first. You can't add them directly to the report designer as it is not a simple type.

For part #2:

Here is an example of how to custmize the ReportViewer

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/LocalizingReportViewer.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know any sample code for the first question?

Comment: No - but I am wondering why would you need such list in the object... Any specific reason??

Comment: For example I have a list of POI (point of interest) places visited by vehicles in a given date interval in the following format: List<List<POI visits>> It is a list of many vehicles, and all vehicles has an own list with its POI visits. I'd like to show them in a report, group by cars and ordered by time interval. This data comes as an object after analyzing positions queried from a database.